# Entity Framework different approaches

Tags: entity-framework-6

Can anyone explain the different approaches used in entity framework and which is better? Have gone through internet and found 3 approaches but still have a doubt which one to prefer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use three type of entity framework approach as per project requirement.

Database First:

1. An existing database can be used
2. Code can be auto-generated.
3. Extensible using partial classes/ T4 templates
4. The developer can update the database manually
5. There is a very good designer, which sync with the underlining database

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/database-first-with-entity-framework.aspx

Code First:

1. There is full control of the model from the Code; no EDMX/designer
2. No manual intervention to DB is required
3. The database is used for data only

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/what-is-code-first.aspx

Model First:

1. Good support with EDMX designer
2. We can visually create the database model
3. EF generates the Code and database script
4. Extensible through partial classes

Comment: Nice presentation Sir.. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Database First is better than other approach.
I think, you should prefer database first approach.